# Quickly convert point features to raster using ArcPy or GDAL

Tags: arcpy, gdal, arcgis-pro

I have a very large point feature collection, about 40 million points, which are obtained by raster conversion, so the arrangement of points is regular (the distance between two columns of points is 30 meters, the distance between two rows is also 30 meters), but the outline of the point feature is not regular (it is the boundary of a province), so how can I quickly convert this point file into a raster? If I use the point to raster tool in ArcGIS, the box will be very slow and will take about two days.

[image]

Comment: Are you limited to arcpy and GDAL?

Comment: Of course not, I just want to convert quickly

Comment: if you do a lot of work using rasters you can look into Grass in QGIS as well.

Comment: If you have a regular point pattern, just write a BIL file to binary using straight Python, then convert from there; it would probably just take minutes.

Comment: Can you give me some more detailed tips? I only found some instructions about BIL files on the Arcgis official website, but there was no instruction on how to convert point files to BIL. At the same time, can it still work if the boundaries of my point files are irregular?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would use GDAL through QGIS. They also have some tools to rasterize features. Plus of course the benefit of having a GUI. It's processing is pretty fast in my opinion. Look into QGIS processing tools.

[image]

Or even use QGIS tools:

[image]